# Does there have any mature method to achieve the tcp traversal?

Tags: tcp, traversal, nat

I'm going to do a test on udp and tcp traversal, I know that udp is easy to achieve traversal, but i don't kown if there have any meture method to achieve tcp traversal? if someone knows, please tell me how to achieve that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience of this but I found this article with source [here](http://nutss.gforge.cis.cornell.edu/stunt.php) with STUNT.

Comment: thanks, Max! But i heard that the stunt method have been confirm to be useless in tcp traversal.